# Loop through two data tables from column to row wise?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames:

DT1: (This data frame's column values I need to edit based on another datatable DT2)

```
BIC         BCC1    BCC2    BCC6    BCC8    BCC9    BCC10   BCC11
990081899A  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
9900023620  0   1   1   0   0   0   0
9900427160  0   1   0   1   0   0   0
990064457TA 1   1   0   1   0   0   0
990066595A  0   0   0   0   0   0   1
990088248A  0   0   0   0   0   0   1
990088882C1 0   0   0   0   0   0   1
990088882C2 0   0   0   1   1   0   0
990088882C3 0   0   0   1   1   0   0
990088882C4 0   0   0   1   1   0   0
990088882C5 0   0   0   1   1   0   0
```

DT2:

```
BCC HIER1   HIER2   HIER3   HIER4   HIER5
BCC8    BCC9    BCC10   BCC11   BCC12   0
BCC9    BCC10   BCC11   BCC12   0   0
BCC10   BCC11   BCC12   0   0   0
BCC11   BCC12   0   0   0   0
BCC17   BCC18   BCC19   0   0   0
BCC18   BCC19   0   0   0   0
BCC27   BCC28   BCC29   BCC80   0   0
BCC28   BCC29   0   0   0   0
BCC46   BCC48   0   0   0   0
BCC54   BCC55   0   0   0   0
BCC57   BCC58   0   0   0   0
BCC70   BCC71   BCC72   BCC103  BCC104  BCC169
```

I want to look up the column names in DT1 though first column values in `DT2$BC`C, according to the hierarchy logic, as:

I want to loop through DT1 column names except first column and nest that loop through DT2 first column values to check if they are equal. If they are equal then get that `DT2$BC`C value and check if `DT1$(DT2$BCC) = 1`, if yes then set value 0 in `DT1` columns are present in `(HIER1, HIER2, HIER3,.......)`

```
Result should be:

BIC         BCC1    BCC2    BCC6    BCC8    BCC9    BCC10   BCC11
990081899A  0   1   0   0   0   0   0
9900023620  0   1   1   0   0   0   0
9900427160  0   1   0   1   0   0   0
990064457TA 1   1   0   1   0   0   0
990066595A  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
990088248A  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
990088882C1 0   0   0   0   0   0   0
990088882C2 0   0   0   1   0   0   0
990088882C3 0   0   0   1   0   0   0
990088882C4 0   0   0   1   0   0   0
990088882C5 0   0   0   1   0   0   0
```

I am doing this now:

```
cols<-setdiff(names(DT1), "HIC")
subs<-as.character(DT2$BCC)
colsHier<-setdiff(names(DT2), "BCC")
paste0("DT1$", eval(cols[i]))<-
         for( i in 1:length(cols)){
         for (k in 1:length(subs)){
         ifelse(cols[i] == subs[k], 
         ifelse(do.call(paste0, list('DT1$', eval(cols[1]),'[]')) == 1,
         for (j in 1:length(colsHeir)){
         if(colsHeir[j]!= 0)
         x<-paste0('DT2$',eval(colsHier[j]))
         paste0('DT1$',eval(x[k])):= 0}
         ,DT1$cols[i]), DT1$cols[i])}}
```

I am trying to match the value of `do.call(paste0, list('DT1$', eval(cols[1]),'[]')) == 1`, but when I am running this expression in R I am getting following:

```
> do.call(paste0, list('DT1$', eval(cols[2]),'[1]'))
[1] "DT1$BCC2[1]"
```

and NOT the value of the cell. How can I access the value of that cell to match with 1.
I am not able get the correct way of doing this. I am sorry for long question. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(reshape2)
```

melt the data

```
dt1.m <- melt(dt1, id = "BIC")
dt2.m <- melt(dt2, id = "BCC")
```

If the dt1.m$variable is equal to one of the values in dt2.m set it to 0

```
dt1.m$value <- ifelse(dt1.m$variable %in% dt2.m$value, 0, dt1.m$value)
```

cast the data into proper form

```
dt1.c <- dcast(dt1.m, ...~variable)
```

Dcast automatically reorders the rows.

Comment: Thanks so much but this is not giving the desired output. May be I did not explain my question correctly.